# Thousand Digit String

Tags: java, string

so this program is basically going through a 1000 digit string(it is shortened on this example) and pull out the 5 digits that make up the highest product . I am able to output the sum of the numbers that make up the highest product, but not the actually digits that made it.

```
public class ThousandDigitString
{
      public static void main(String[] args){
      String num = "73167176531";
      int product = 0;
      int product2 = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < num.length()-4; i++)
      {
          product2 = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i))*   Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+1)) * Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+2)) *
                      Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+3))* Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+4));;
          if(product2 > product)
          {
              product=product2;
          }
      }
      System.out.println(product);        
    }
}
```

Comment: So is the problem that you want to print or otherwise store the digits that make up the product?

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Are they supposed to be consecutive? Because I'd think 7*6*7*7*6 would give the highest product there, and your `product2` will not find that.

Comment: you should be far more specific about the question. for example the info that the digits should be **consecutive** is missing

Answer (score 2):

```
int startingIndex = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < num.length()-4; i++)
  {
      product2 = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i))*         Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+1)) * Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+2)) *
                  Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+3))* Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+4));;
      if(product2 > product)
      {
          product=product2;
          startingIndex = i;
      }
  }
  System.out.println(product);
  // retrieve digits from string at startingIndex to startingIndex + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can save the individual characters into an array or ArrayList and when you check if product2 > product save the array off

For example:

```
public class ThousandDigitString
{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      String num = "73167176531";
      int product = 0;
      int product2 = 0;
      int index = 0;
      int[] numbers = new int[5];
      for(int i = 0; i < num.length()-4; i++)
      {
          product2 = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i))*   Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+1)) * Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+2)) *
                      Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+3))* Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+4));;
          if(product2 > product)
          {
              product=product2;
              index = i;
          }
      }
      numbers[0] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(index));
      numbers[1] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(index+1));
      numbers[2] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(index+2));
      numbers[3] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(index+3));
      numbers[4] = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(index+4));

      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
      System.out.println(product);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you replace product2 with product, you could store the 5 digits that make up the product, then at the end print them out. Either in 5 new variables, or an array.

```
public class ThousandDigitString
{
      public static void main(String[] args){
      String num = "73167176531";
      int product = 0;
      int product2 = 0;
      int i1 = 0;
      int i2 = 0;
      int i3 = 0;
      int i4 = 0;
      int i5 = 0;

      for(int i = 0; i < num.length()-4; i++)
      {
          product2 = Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i))*   Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+1)) * Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+2)) *
                      Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+3))* Character.getNumericValue(num.charAt(i+4));;
          if(product2 > product)
          {
              int i1 = num.charAt(i);
              int i2 = num.charAt(i+1);
              int i3 = num.charAt(i+2);
              int i4 = num.charAt(i+3);
              int i5 = num.charAt(i+4);
          }
      }
      System.out.println(product);
      System.out.println(i1);  
      System.out.println(i2);  
      System.out.println(i3);  
      System.out.println(i4);  
      System.out.println(i5);          
    }
}
```

An array would be neater than individual variables, if you're familiar with them.

Comment: Or just store the starting index of the 5 digits in a single int variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is much easier than you are making it. Parse the string as an array maintain find out biggest 5 digits. You need not actually multiply within loop.

Once you find out top 5 digits. these are the digits you want. convert them into int and multiply them, that gives you the product.

Comment: ops question was unclear, but hes actually searching for the biggest product of 5 **consecutive** digits.